# Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

Tags: android

занимаюсь по учебнику
создала новый проект
при запуске выдает ошибку
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.and08.lifecycle/android.and08.lifecycle.LifeCycleActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

LifeCycleActivity.java

```
package android.and08.lifecycle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class LifeCycleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_life_cycle);
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "\"onCreate\" durchlaufen");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "\"onStart\" durchlaufen");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "\"onResume\" durchlaufen");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestart(){
        super.onRestart();
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "\"onRestart\" durchlaufen");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "\"onPause\" durchlaufen");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "\"onStop\" durchlaufen");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "\"onDestroy\" durchlaufen");
    }
}
```

activity_life_cycle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="android.and08.lifecycle.LifeCycleActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_lifecycle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

2-й вариант activity_life_cycle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="android.and08.lifecycle.LifeCycleActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_lifecycle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

таже проблема : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.and08.lifecycle/android.and08.lifecycle.LifeCycleActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout

build.gradle (Modulle app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.and08.lifecycle"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: приложите к вопросу `build.gradle` пжл

Comment: Попробуйте в студии `InvalidateCache and Restart` сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить в `build.gradle` (*Module: app*) в блок `dependencies {...`

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Последнюю версию можно глянуть [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project)

Comment: не работает; таже ошибка

Comment: @LenaKosareva: обновили `sync now`?

Comment: синхронизировала проект

Comment: @LenaKosareva: помогло?

Comment: нет        если поменять на RelativeLayout как в учебнике то таже ошибка

Comment: @LenaKosareva: поменяли корень? приложите к вопросу конкретное состояние кода в которой возникает ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Что-то я сделала не так при создании проекта, создала заново и всё заработало.
Спасибо TimurVI

Comment: Вы лучше не пишите благодарность ответом на свой вопрос, а поставьте галочку под ответом @TimurVI если он вам помог.